# React-hook-form: Reset / Empty An Input File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, input-field

I am new to React and I want to create a button to reset/empty the input file for edit functionality. I am using MUI and React-hook-form. When I clicked the reset button, the image had already changed, and the input file also stated 'No file chosen', however when I clicked the submit button, the file was still there and sent to my backend. However, it should be null and hence will not be sent to the backend.

I am trying by using useRef and setting the value of the input file to null, I tried console.log for checking, and the value is null. But the value sent is still the latest image I uploaded. This is my full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Box, TextField, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import LoopIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Loop";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export default function MyInput(props) {
  const { name, control, label, width, image } = props;
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const inputFile = useRef(null);

  const handleReset = () => {
    if (inputFile.current) {
      inputFile.current.value = null;
      setFile(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: { width } }}>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
          <>
            <Box>
              <TextField
                inputRef={inputFile}
                sx={{ maxWidth: "75%" }}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  onChange(e.target.files[0]);
                  setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
                }}
                id="outlined-basic"
                label={label}
                variant="outlined"
                value={value?.fileName}
                type="file"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                  accept: "image/png, image/jpeg",
                }}
                error={!!error}
                helperText={error?.message}
              />
              <IconButton onClick={handleReset}>
                <LoopIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
            <img
              className="image"
              src={file ? file : image}
              alt={file ? "Error: Image cannot be displayed" : undefined}
              style={{ maxWidth: "100%", height: "auto", marginTop: "20px" }}
            />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </Box>
  );
```

}

I am new to resetField, I don't know exactly how to pass it to another file, the above code is myInput.jsx, and this is the part of code where I am calling it, where should I pass the resetField?

```
const { handleSubmit, setValue, setError, control, resetField } = 

useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submission)}>
        <MyInput
            label="Image"
            name="image"
            control={control}
            width={"35%"}
            image={image}
         />
    </form>
)
```

Any idea how to make the value of my input file become null when I click the reset button? What am I missing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not update the `file` state inside `handleReset`?

Comment: Hi, I already did the setFile in the handleReset, but this is only for resetting the image preview to the default value. Could you explain me more about your solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to use vanillajs selectors in React, I hope you are using that of something as a "last resort" thing.

You are using `react-hook-form` , so there is no need to manage the state yourself.

I am not familiar with MUI, so I am not sure exactly how the `<TextField />` works.

it seems to me that if you are using something like `react-hook-form` you need to reset the data there, and not locally in the input with some hardcoded `useState()`

I would need more information about the implementation outside this component, but basically the `useForm()` hook from `react-hook-form` has a `resetField()` and `reset()` method that you can access to "reset" this data, additionally if you have access to the "control".

reset: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset
resetField: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/resetfield

The `useEffect()` hook in there does not have any meaning really, you could get rid of it, these 3 constants here also should not have any "control" over, You should control the state of the form and of the Field with `useForm()`>

```
// these should/can be removed.
const [file, setFile] = useState();
const [old, setOld] = useState();
const inputFile = useRef(null);
```

If you have some kind of codesandbox I can look at, perhaps I could go into more detail about this.

Comment: Hi I already made some changes to my code, but it still not working, I read about the resetField, but I am confused how to implement it since I have separated file. I am new in react-hook-form, could you help me with that

Comment: So I can see you have the `resetField` method there on top 
```
const { handleSubmit, setValue, setError, control, resetField } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
```
You also have `setValue` , that could also override the value.
Now you have `handleReset` function, you could put there the `resetField('image')` method and it willl trigger on click. 
this is just related to how JSX works, passing the function as a prop and triggering form inside

Comment: Yes, I know but for the setValue I used it in the same file when I fetch the old data and I accessed it in another file as value like I  stated 'render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } })'. How about the resetField? I where should I used it? And how to access it inside the Controller render in another file. setValue accessed in render field as value, how about this resetField? also immediately use the resetField in the handleReset is not possible since it is out of the Controller